# Does Windows 8 still needs codecs to be manually installed

Tags: windows, video-codecs

Ever since XP times powerusers have learned to try to keep the installed codecs up to date.
I personally used the k-lite codec pack for fresh system installs.

Ever since Windows 7 it seems like things have changed in the codec world. I don't remember if I had any trouble viewing video files without a codec installation.
This question basically answers some part of my question: [Is there still need for codecs in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/333062/is-there-still-need-for-codecs-in-windows-7)

Now have things changed in Windows 8 with respect to DivX embedded support?

Comment: Why don't you try without and see how that goes? I haven't used a codec pack for windows since XP-SP3 came out. (but then I use vlc & mplayer)